# Emacs won't mouse wheel scroll on Ubuntu 15.10 with Cinnamon

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 using the Cinnamon interface instead of the default.  When I run emacs 24.5.1 in an X interface, almost everything works well with the mouse, except the mouse wheel scrolling fails.  In the Messages buffer when I try to scroll up, it says:

C-M-( is undefined

And when I scroll down:

C-M-) is undefined

Comment: Do you really mean Emacs 14 or did you mistype 24?

Comment: What is the output of pressing `C-h k` and then scrolling the mouse up or down?  This should describe the key and what it is bound to.  e.g. my scroll up is `<mouse-4>` and runs `mwheel-scroll` from `mwheel.el`

Comment: Yes, it is emacs 24.5.1, the standard one coming from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: C-h k gives doesn't describe anything, it just dumps more "C-M-( is undefined" messages in the Messages buffer.  Other mouse buttons do display as things in the Help window.  <mouse-1>, 2,3 all work. Mouse 6/7 (left right on the scroll wheel) display as "<mouse-6> is undefined" and "<mouse-7> is undefined" respectively.

Comment: Should I map C-M-( and C-M-) to scroll?  If so, what should I map them to?  My .emacs file already includes (mouse-wheel-mode t)

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you start it as `emacs -Q` to not load your init file(s)?  I've never had to do anything to setup mouse scrolling except in terminal emacs.

Comment: Yep, does exactly the same thing.  "C-M-) is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I've come up against this same problem on Ubuntu-15.10.  It appears that the mwheel.el code isn't being loaded by default.

You can work around this by adding these lines to your ~/.emacs file:

```
(load "/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/mwheel.elc")
(mouse-wheel-mode t)
```

Comment: Didn't help. Not sure what else to try. Tried binding `C-M-(` and `C-M-)` to lambda function that scroll up/down with 4 lines -- didn't work as well.